# How to write a mapFunction in Java8 in spark code ? Error: map(Function1, Encoder) not applicable for the arguments

Tags: apache-spark, java-8, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have a mapFunction as below

```
Function1<CompanyInfoRecordNew, CompanyInfoTransformedRecord> mapFunction = ( record ) ->{

        CompanyInfoTransformedRecord  transRec = new CompanyInfoTransformedRecord();
        //popluate 
    return transRec ;
    };
```

Which takes CompanyInfoRecordNew object and return CompanyInfoTransformedRecord.

**But while invoking this as below**

JavaRDD companyInfoTransformedRecord  = baseDs.map(mapFunction, comanyInfoTransEncoder);

**Giving Error :**

The method map(Function1, Encoder) in the type Dataset is not applicable for the arguments (Function1, Encoder)

What is wrong here ?

Code Link for the same :

https://gist.github.com/BdLearnerr/cbfea1c8471557bb33449f882cc1854a

**How to return a List from map function?**

Code updated in the link

https://gist.github.com/BdLearnerr/cbfea1c8471557bb33449f882cc1854a

**Section 2 :**

```
MapFunction<CompanyInfoRecordNew, List<CompanyInfoTransformedRecord>>  mapFunction = ( record ) ->{

            List<CompanyInfoTransformedRecord>  transRecList = new ArrayList<CompanyInfoTransformedRecord>();

return transRecList ;
}


   Dataset<List<CompanyInfoTransformedRecord>> companyInfoTransformedRecords = baseDs.map(mapFunction, comanyInfoTransEncoder);
```

//Error

> The method map(Function1, Encoder) in the
>   type Dataset is not applicable for the arguments
>   MapFunction>,
>   Encoder)

```
companyInfoTransformedRecord.show();
```

Not able to do show due to error  , how to get show() working. ??

Answer (score 1):

Your imports are wrong, instead of this:

```
import org.apache.calcite.linq4j.function.Function1;
```

Use this

```
org.apache.spark.api.java.function.MapFunction;

baseDs.map(new MapFunction<CompanyInfoRecordNew, CompanyInfoTransformedRecord>() {...}, encoder);
```

Comment: FunctionX is `Scala-specific`  and MapFunction is `Java-specific`

Comment: This one `org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function` is used for JavaRDD. Dataset takes either `scala.Function[1-22]` or  `org.apache.spark.api.java.function. MapFunction `

Comment: Could you create a simple, reproducible example? I will try to help.

Answer (score 0):

To take an object and return list of objects we need to use flatmap instead of map as below

```
FlatMapFunction<Original, Derived>  flatMapFunction = ( record ) ->{

            List<Derived>  transRecList = new ArrayList<Derived>();

            Derived  transRec = new Derived();

            transRecList.add(transRec);

            Derived  transRec2 = new Derived();
                transRecList.add(transRec2);

            return (Iterator<Derived>) transRecList.iterator();
        };
```

Dataset Deriveds = baseDs.flatMap(flatMapFunction, comanyInfoTransEncoder);